# KILE: editor for .tex files does not show

Tags: editors, ubuntu, kile

I am not sure if this is a very trivial, or an advanced problem, but since I updated to Ubuntu 16.04, my Kile LaTeX editor stopped working. I can open my `.tex` files, and even build them (ViewPDF, and Okular will open the `.pdf`) but I can not see the `.tex` file any more! I used to select the file in the file explorer on the left, double click, and the file will open on the right (standard setting for Kile I guess) but now, nothing will happen. I can not seem to find a way to open the `.tex` files in Kile. the editor seems to have dissappeared. Has anyone encountered something like that before?
I attached a picture of my Kile. as I said, I click on a `.tex` file, but it just wont open. All stays gray as it is on the screenshot.
Regards 
Christopher 
[image: kile as it looks after the update]

Comment: apt-get purge and re-install did not do either, by the way

Answer (score 1):

did you solve your problem already? Today the same thing happend to me as well. Im using Lubuntu 16.06.

After I deleted the files: `.kde/shared/apps/kile` and `./kde/shared/config/kilerc` I did:

1. `apt-get remove kile` (theoretically not needed)
2. `apt-get purge kile`
3. `apt-get install kile`

Now it works again. I hope it helps, good luck!